# How to prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(\sqrt{n}-2)^2 \over n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1} }$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(\sqrt{n}-2)^2 \over n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1} }$

I tried using the ratio test but i cant cancel anything out.

Answer (score 4):

Limit comparison test:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(\sqrt n-2)^2}{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}}{\frac1{2n}}=1$$

Thus, as $k\to\infty$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^k{(\sqrt{n}-2)^2 \over n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1} }\sim\sum_{n=1}^k\frac1{2n}$$

which is the harmonic series and diverges.

Comment: The limit is $\frac12$.

Comment: @user296113 Sorry, that's right.  (honestly just compared the powers, but I should've noticed that, thanks)

Comment: On the last line, it might be better *not* to start the index at $n=1$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Why is that?

Comment: The $\sim$ is true when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Like so?

Comment: If the limit was $1$, we wouldn't be able to conclude anything. Just a friendly reminder.

Comment: The last line needn't be true. Since $\sum \frac 1n$ diverges, you get asymptotic equivalence on the partial sums, not the tails.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Actually I think it's the tails.  Last time I checked the proof of the limit comparison test, that is.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt No, with **divergent non negative** series, you get equivalence of [partial sums](http://imgur.com/ONyeBRH)

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Huh, ok.  Never knew...

Answer (score 2):

By *equivalence*:
$$(\sqrt n-2)^2\sim_\infty\sqrt n^2=n,\enspace n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}\sim_\infty 2n^2, \enspace\text{whence}\quad\frac{(\sqrt n-2)^2}{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}\sim_\infty \frac{n}{2n^2}=\frac1{2n},$$
which diverges.

Comment: :D Which was my line of logic when I wrote my answer.